# Debugging Android application over adb

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, remote-debugging

I just have a simple question targeting debugging via adb.

Is there just one way to debug your android application via the adb when you install additionally the app "wifi over adb" to connect your android studio debuger mode with your adb hardware device?

Comment: do you mean adb over wifi?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Answer (score 1):

Debuging android application over adb without USB cable.

Steps:-

1 . Install the ADB Wireless app from play store using this link  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=za.co.henry.hsu.adbwirelessbyhenry&hl=en

2. after the install ADB wireless app clik on Show wifi IP.It shown your mobile IP address over the wifi.
3. Now find your IDE path ex.

Eclipse:- D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools

Android Studio:- D:\Android Studio\sdk\platform-tools

4. press Window + R key
5. type cmd

change the directory C:\users\admin> to your IDE path ex. D:\Android   Studio\sdk\platform-tools.

6. Connect your device with usb (only first time)
7. type adb devices

it show the connected device list with alphanumeric id.

8. type adb tcpip 5555
9. remove usb cable
10. type adb connect your_mobile_ip:5555
    here your_mobile_ip means ADB Wireless show mobile IP.
    ex. adb connect xxx.xxx.x.xxx:5555
11. Now go to your Android studio and edit some thing.

go to run -> Edit configuration  -> your app name in your Run/Debug Configuration window come to the Target device panel ->choose show chooser dialog. click apply-> ok.

12. adb disconnect xxx.xxx.x.xxx:5555

    for disconnecting your device.
    I hope this will help you

Answer (score -1):

#### if you want to debug via wifi then you simply follow the following  steps
first set the adb path in envirorment variable
 
for example D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools;

1) press Window + R key
2) type cmd
3) Connect your device with usb (only first time)
4) type adb tcpip 5555 in command promt
5) remove usb 
6) in cmp again type command: adb connect xxx.xxx.x.xxx (Your Wi-Fi IP)

I hope this will help you.
:)

Comment: I did this before, but when I ran the app in the android Studio then I couldn't connect to the adb-device, just with the app which I've installed additionally it shows me my android device in the window where you determine your running device hardware device/simulator.